# Userform needed only once

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a new VBA user.  I have a workbook with multiple worksheets. Each one has it own userform for data entry. The userform shows when I click on the sheet. After I'm done entering data, the worksheet is populated and the userform closes (unload). All this works well. However, after the initial data entry is complete, the goal is to use the data on the worksheets for other applications and the userform is no longer needed. What is the code or the terminology to say the userform should not reappear again when the worksheet is clicked on? Currently, I red X out of the userform. If I click the command button to close, it repopulates and I lose all my data.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to save somewhere the information that the form has already been used. Many possibilities (global, static, some hidden cell, etc)

Answer (score 2):

As A.S.H commented; you could store the information in a number of ways. An easy example is declaring a variable outside of the Macro:

```
Public FormOpened as boolean
```

And then set FormOpened as true once the form has been shown. Then you could add a check to the start of the mouse-click macro:

```
If FormOpened = True then Exit sub
```